# Git not using SSH when doing 'git clone'

Tags: git, bitbucket, redhat

I'm using BitBucket and SSH in RedHat.

Since I'm behind a corporate firewall, I'm using *corkscrew* to use our proxy and login.

When I do:

```
ssh -T bitbucket.org
```

Everything works and I get the

```
Logged in as username. You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

But when I try to clone from my repo:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:myUser/myRepo.git
```

I get:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname bitbucket.org: Name or service not known
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The repo is set to SSH and I can clone from my Windows machine, using the exact same settings with Git Bash.

What am I missing?

**Update 1:** As was pointed out below, `git clone` is not using my SSH configs at all. I can run `ssh` directly and it works, but `git clone` fails to even connect to the server. Why would git not use SSH?

Comment: I don't know anything about corkscrew but maybe it isn't working when git is called. Seems like it requires a config and perhaps git is going around that and directly to ssh?

Comment: You're right. I messed around with the SSH settings so that it should throw an error with any SSH executing, and when I use git clone, it doesn't even show. So `git clone` is not using SSH in the first place. NO IDEA why, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're running `git clone` under `sudo`, which means you're running it under the `root` account, not under your own account.

Since you're not running under your own user account, `git` doesn't have access to your account's ssh configuration. The `git clone` command is using ssh, it's just using it with the `root` account's settings, not with yours.

You said in a comment that you're cloning into a subdirectory of the Apache root folder. That folder is owned by the `root` account, so *of course* your account doesn't have permission to write to it.

In general, you shouldn't use the `root` account for anything that you can do from a non-`root` account, just as a matter of safety. If you can run the `git clone` command from your own user account, you have less risk of doing something that breaks your system, *and* `ssh` will use your personal configuration. (Modifying `root`'s ssh configuration will do the job, but I don't think it's a good idea.)

If you want to avoid running `git` commands as `root`, you need to do the `git clone` into a directory that you have permission to write to.

One solution is, after you're created your directory under the Apache root directory, to use `sudo chown` to change the ownership of that directory to your account. You'll then be able to write to that directory, including running `git clone` without `sudo`.

Or you can use `sudo chown` to change just the *group* ownership of the directory to some group you're a member of -- probably a group created for this purpose. Then use `chmod g+w` to grant group write permission. Now you'll be able to write to the directory even though it's still owned by `root`.

Or you can just clone into a subdirectory of your home directory, and then use `sudo ln -s` to create a symbolic link to your directory under the Apache root directory. (A drawback of that is that it's not obvious, by looking under your home directory, that Apache depends on this subdirectory.)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I thought about creating a symlink from my user folder, but like you said, it's not obvious so I didn't like it. But that other option using `sudo chown` sounds much better and cleaner. I'll give that a try. Thank you again! :D

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `git clone` was using the global SSH settings instead of my user's settings. So I had to create new keys at `/etc/ssh/` and add my corkscrew proxy settings in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

I'm still a Linux newbie so I could be wrong, but I'm going to assume this happened because I have to do `sudo git clone`. Maybe this forces the terminal to use global settings instead of user settings.

I'll check with our IT department to confirm this.

In any case, if you have similar issues, check which SSH settings `git` is using, global's or user's.

Comment: `sudo` means that your `git clone` process runs as the `root` user, not as you, so it won't use your personal settings. But why do you have to run `git clone` as root? That's rarely a good idea.

Comment: I wish I knew. But I get `permission denied` when running it without `sudo`. This is a corporate VM so they don't give me root access, sudo is the best I can do. But I'll ask them to see what can be done about it.

Comment: Permission denied for what? The `git` command? The `git-clone` command? Your local repo? If you ran `git clone` as `root` once, then `root` owns your local repo directory. Try doing a `git clone` without `sudo` in a new directory. (BTW, `sudo` *is* root access.)

Comment: Permission denied to create the directory for the repo. Even if the directory already exists, I had to create using `sudo mkdir`. So it ends up being the same, right? The only place I can do stuff freely is in my user directory `/tank/username/`, but I want to work in Apache root folder.